# Deployment with Hardhat doesn't work correctly

Tags: deployment, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I'm currently trying to deploy a solidity 0.7.6 contract with Hardhat 2.6.2. No errors are shown when compiling and deploying the contract to the Rinkeby testnet, and a contract address is returned. When trying to transact with this contract, it gets stuck, and checking Etherscan there is no contract creation transaction visible. When loading this contract address in Remix, I can transact with the contract, but when calling for a value, no value is returned.

Contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.7.6;

contract Greeter {

    string public greeting;

    constructor(string memory test) {
        greeting = test;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to explicitly define a `getGreeting()` and try returning the value. Can you try this?